# Sitecore 8.1 Update-3 throwing "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." in admin interface

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

At some point after upgrading to Sitecore 8.1 (we're currently on Update-3) we started seeing the following error in ELMAH:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Full stack trace below.

```
System.FormatException: Could not map index document field to property "CreatedDate" on type Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SitecoreUISearchResultItem : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldUtcDateTimeValueConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter.ReadFromIndexStorage(Object indexValue, String fieldName, Type destinationType)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentTypeMapInfo.SetProperty(Object target, String propertyName, String documentFieldName, Object value)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentTypeMapInfo.SetProperty(Object target, String propertyName, String documentFieldName, Object value)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapper`1.MapFieldValuesToType[TElement](IDictionary`2 fieldValues, TElement result, DocumentTypeMapInfo documentTypeMapInfo)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapper`1.MapToType[TElement](TDocument document, SelectMethod selectMethod, IEnumerable`1 virtualFieldProcessors, IEnumerable`1 executionContexts, SearchSecurityOptions securityOptions)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchResults`1.<GetSearchHits>d__2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This can be reproduced by logging into Sitecore Desktop and opening the Content Editor (Sitecore button > Content Editor).

A while back I had found [Indexing DateTime fields – Sitecore 7 Content Search](https://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/01/30/indexing-datetime-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/) which implementing for 8.1 resulted in a patch config like the following:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <!-- Override Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config to work around possible bug. -->
        <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
                <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                    <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                            <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate">
                                <patch:attribute name="format">yyyyMMdd</patch:attribute>
                            </field>
                            <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate">
                                <patch:attribute name="format">yyyyMMdd</patch:attribute>
                            </field>
                        </fieldNames>
                    </fieldMap>
                </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
            </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Is this the best fix for this issue, or is there something misconfigured with?

Comment: Can you try to delete all indexes and rebuild all indexes again. I had a similar issue, some  field had some corrupted values

Comment: If I remember correctly with that patch there was also a setting AlternateDateFormats - this allows you to have multiple different date formats (separated by pipe). It looks like the converter class is trying to use this setting to convert strings into dates. Might be that Sitecore 8 is using a different date format now. Not sure if Sitecore 8 supercedes the patch, decompile the DateFieldReader in Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider to see if the bug is still there.

Comment: Btw can you check you have all the config in place for this patch? - it requires more that just 2 field declarations.

Comment: @IanGraham The above patch was enough to remove the errors we were seeing. When you say patch, are you talking about the site I linked to, or an official patch? If the latter, can you provide a link?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Done. According to Luke 3.1.0 __smallcreateddate and __smallupdateddate are still `yyyyMMdd` format.

Comment: I was talking about the link you provided. The issue is with the IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter Class when buckets are indexed- it is expecting a format other than yyyyMMdd for those fields. The link you provided has code for the converter class as well which will allow different date times rather than just using the default. I would try removing the patch and testing if it us still valid in Sitecore 8 as I know there has been some changes with UTC formats in Sitecore 8. If it is needed then implement the Converter class to go with it.

Comment: One other thing - do you use the patch you added above in conjunction with a custom index? If so you could move those 2 date field declarations to a separate Lucene  index configuration file rather than them being in the default Lucene configuration file.

Comment: Nope, not a custom index. I also only implemented the patch config; creating the convertor class seemingly wasn't necessary.

Comment: Dang it. Found my own question after running into this again with an upgrade to Sitecore 9 ...